# How does ListLogLinearPlot work and can it obtained from a ListPlot?

Tags: plotting, data, logarithmic-scale

Consider the following example plot for some point data

`ListLogLinearPlot[data[[All, {1, 2}]], Joined -> True]`

[image]

**I need to know exactly how `ListLogLinearPlot` works** so I can  implement it in code myself, in other words is there a way to make the data table first and then just plot it using `ListPlot`.

PS:*Though the question really isn't specific to a particular dataset, I can provide it if need be.*

Comment: You can simplify your code to `ListLogLinearPlot[gg, Joined -> True]` This can also be done with `ListPlot[gg, Joined -> True, ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", None}]` or `ListLinePlot[gg, ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", None}]`

Comment: @BobHanlon, Thank you it works. But is there a way to make the data table first and then just plot it using `ListPlot` only without using the log as a `ScalingFunction`. I want data that could directly plot this graph without any use of scaling in the plot options.

Comment: To get results equivalent to `ListLogLinearPlot` you will have to take a `Log` somewhere. `ListLinePlot[{Log10[#[[1]]], #[[2]]} & /@ gg]` produces the same curve but the axes label needs to be adjusted. That's part of what the scaling functions do.

Answer (score 4):

> But is there a way to make the data table first and then just plot it
> using ListPlot only without using the log as a ScalingFunction

From help, `ListLogLinearPlot` applies log on the `x` and makes the x-axis log scale.  To do this by hand, using the example from help (since it has less data and easier to work with than your example)

```
data = Table[{n, Sqrt[n]}, {n, 100}];
ListLogLinearPlot[data]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now to that directly, using `ListPlot` just do

```
data2 = Table[{Log[n], Sqrt[n]}, {n, 100}];
ListPlot[data2, Mesh -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Ofcourse `ListLogLinearPlot` does more. You need to also fix the tick labels. For now, a quick way could be to do it manually using the `Ticks` options which takes list of 2 numbers. The first is the value and the second is the label:

```
ListPlot[data2, Mesh -> All, 
 Ticks -> {{{Log[1.1], 1}, {Log[5], 5}, {Log[10], 10}, {Log[50], 
     50}, {Log[100], 100}}, Automatic}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now it is much closer to the output of `ListLogLinearPlot` but I think more refinement can be done on the ticks (the above does not show the minor ticks for example), that is what ScalingFunction do automatically for you. But if you do not want to use these you have do it by hand.

There are many posts here about how to make custom tick labels.  But one of the reasons for using the build in `ListLogLinearPlot` command, is that it does all this automatically for you and gets all the ticks right.

If you want to see the ticks used in with  `ListLogLinearPlot` you can do

```
data = Table[{n, Sqrt[n]}, {n, 100}];
p = ListLogLinearPlot[data]
AbsoluteOptions[p, Ticks]
```

But the above is basically it. Just take the log of the `x` value and plot it against the `y` value.